# Dynamic jquery table sort

Tags: jquery

I am Using http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-options-headers.html

```
 $("#sort-table").tablesorter( 
       {headers: { 

            0: { 
                sorter: false 
               }, 

            dynamic_value: { 
                     sorter: false 
             } 
        } 
    });
```

How Can pass Dynamic_value for example from $('.header').length ?

```
<thead>
  <tr>
       <th width="20"><?php echo $check;?></th>
       <th class="header">FullName</th>
       <th class="header">Rank</th>
       <th class="header">Email</th>
       <th class="header">Position</th>
       <th width="15"></th>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you want to apply `sorter: false` to a certain column of which the number has to be calculated dynamically. As far as I know, JavaScript doesn't allow any direct syntax for that, so you'll have to go with the following:

```
headerset = {
               0: { 
                    sorter: false 
               }
            // any other static column here
            };
// repeat the following line for each dynamic value
headerset[dynamicvalue] = { sorter: false };
// the variable headerset now contains the header settings
// you can apply them to the tablesorter
$("#sort-table").tablesorter({ headers: headerset });
```

It's not elegant, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for above query is as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{ 
    // extend the default setting to always sort on the first column
    $.tablesorter.defaults.sortList = [[0,0]];
    var newheader={
        1:{sorter:false},
        4:{sorter:false}
    };
    $(".tablesorter").tablesorter({headers:newheader});
});
```

We can also extends options using json string as shown here.
I have created a bin with the solution on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpcd